# Why am i getting an "Odd number of elements in anonymous hash " warning

Tags: perl, hash

I'm getting a warning in my perl code and don't know why...

Warning:

```
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at /Users/../Tree.pm line 56.
```

Which gives me that line :

```
$dic->{$firstLetter}={$letra};
```

Is there a problem with the implementation?

I mean, it passes all the tests, but it's giving me these errors ... like 10 times always on the same line!
Please, some advice will be welcome! :)

```
sub add_word{
    my ($self,$word) = @_ ;
    my $dic = $self->{'dic'};
    my @array = split(//,$word);
    my $firstLetter = shift @array;
    for my $letra(@array){
            if(!$dic->{$firstLetter}){
                    $dic->{$firstLetter} = {$letra};
                    $dic = $dic->{$firstLetter};
            }
            else{
                    if($dic->{$firstLetter}){
                            $dic = $dic->{$firstLetter};
                    }
            }
            $firstLetter = $letra;
    }
    $dic->{$firstLetter} = {"\$" => "\$"};
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`= {$letra}` is creating a hashref with a key but no value and trying to assign it.

You probably want to just assign the scalar you have:

```
$dic->{$firstLetter} = $letra;
```

Although you might want:

```
$dic->{$firstLetter} = { someKey => $letra };
```

or

```
$dic->{$firstLetter} = { $letra => "someValue" };
```

Comment: what i want is $dic reference to an other hash but i want only to add they key from the other hash! Why will you ask me ? Because i want to interactively add hash to hash to hash ! And only when there is no other things to put i add a key and a value at the end !

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you mean.

Comment: I will post my function maybe it will be better to understand !

Answer (score 2):

It's good that you have `warnings` turned on. When you use `{ ... }` in an expression like `{$letra}`, you are constructing an *anonymous hash reference*. A hash wants to be initialized with key/value pairs. So when you write

```
$dic->{$firstLetter}={$letra};
```

That's almost the same as

```
my %anon = ( $letra );
$dic->{$firstLetter} = \%anon;
```

That hash will be messed up, because it has a key but no value. Thus, hashes want to have an even-sized list when they are constructed, so every key has a value. With an odd-size list as you have, it emits a warning.

My guess is you probably just want to assign a simple scalar. So try

```
$dic->{$firstLetter} = $letra;
```

And don't be afraid of the spacebar. :) It makes things easier to read.

Comment: ahahah yeah i won't be afraid with the spacebar ! xD
But as i said it, what i want is $dic reference to an other hash but i want only to add they key from the other hash! Why will you ask me ? Because i want to interactively add hash to hash to hash ! And only when there is no other things to put i add a key and a value at the end !